# grep doesn't give output with files containing regular expressions

Tags: windows, grep

I have a file regular.txt containing regular expressions as below:

```
("(FinalImageInfo|ImageInfo)".*){2}
("(Process|signal|ready)".*){3}
("(detected|overlap)".*){2}
```

My sample test file:
Test1.txt:

```
AAA BBB CCCC
DDDD FinalImageInfo EEE ImageInfo FFFF
GGGGG HHHHHH
```

when I use regular.txt to search strings in files using grep, grep does not give any output, not even error message.I have tried the following command:

```
grep  -E -f regular.txt *.txt
```

Has anyone any idea why my grep command is not working with regular expressions from a file?

Note: I am testing grep on Windows 7 and grep version is 6.1.0.209

Comment: That file works for me. Are you absolutely certain those regular expressions  match any text? For example, the first one matches `"FinalImageInfo" blah "FinalImageInfo" blah blah"` - is that what you intend? Can you provide a few lines of the text file that you think should match?

Comment: @Bryan Oakley:
The following is one of my test file and it surely contains the strings:
test1.txt:  
AAA BBB CCCC
DDDD FinalImageInfo EEE ImageInfo FFFF
GGGGG HHHHHH

Comment: Add to your question: OS/distribution with version, grep version and content of your test file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with your grep command, the problem is simply that the files you are searching don't have any text that matches the patterns.

The problem seems to be that you copied the expressions straight from the command line, but when you use them on the command line you have to add quoting characters which are stripped away by the shell. When you put the expressions in a file, you don't have to use the quoting characters. What goes in the file needs to be a valid regular expression with no extra quoting characters.

You need to strip the `"`s from your expressions:

```
((FinalImageInfo|ImageInfo).*){2}
((Process|signal|ready).*){3}
((detected|overlap).*){2}
```

Comment: When I have used the regular expression on commandline against the test file , it gives me output.. The following is my test file, 
test1.txt:  

    AAA BBB CCCC
    DDDD FinalImageInfo EEE ImageInfo FFFF
    GGGGG HHHHHH

I tried the following grep command on command line:

    grep -E ("(FinalImageInfo|ImageInfo)".*){2} *.txt

And got the following output:

    test1.txt:DDDD FinalImageInfo EEE ImageInfo FFFF

I don't understand what is the problem when I used with regular expression file

Comment: Great. Thank you so much for helping me.. Now I am able to read from pattern file